# import weasyprint gives AttributeError: 'OutStream' object has no attribute 'buffer'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, attributeerror, weasyprint

I've tried importing a set of libraries in jupyter notebook the following is my code

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install openpyxl
!{sys.executable} -m pip install weasyprint
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pdfkit
!{sys.executable} -m pip install wkhtmltopdf
!{sys.executable} -m pip install mpld3

import boto3
import re
import os
import yaml
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_excel
from pandas import read_csv
from datetime import datetime 
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from weasyprint import HTML
import pdfkit
import mpld3
```

This worked perfectly for 3 months. But now when it comes to importing HTML from weasyprint it gives the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-60677dd023a4> in <module>
     20 from datetime import timedelta
     21 from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
---> 22 from weasyprint import HTML
     23 import pdfkit
     24 import mpld3

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py in <module>
    321 # Work around circular imports.
    322 from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa isort:skip
--> 323 from .html import (  # noqa isort:skip
    324     HTML5_UA_COUNTER_STYLE, HTML5_UA_STYLESHEET, HTML5_PH_STYLESHEET,
    325     find_base_url)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/weasyprint/html.py in <module>
     21 from .css.counters import CounterStyle
     22 from .formatting_structure import boxes
---> 23 from .images import SVGImage
     24 from .logger import LOGGER
     25 from .urls import get_url_attribute

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/weasyprint/images.py in <module>
     11 from itertools import cycle
     12 
---> 13 import pydyf
     14 from PIL import Image
     15 

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydyf/__init__.py in <module>
    402 
    403 
--> 404 class PDF:
    405     """PDF document."""
    406     def __init__(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydyf/__init__.py in PDF()
    506         self.write_line(b'%%EOF', output)
    507 
--> 508     def write(self, output=sys.stdout.buffer):
    509         """Write PDF to output.
    510 

AttributeError: 'OutStream' object has no attribute 'buffer'
```

this code runs in a sagemaker notebook instance. I've setup the lifecycle configurations to run the notebook when starting up the instance. therefore i need to install the libraries through the code. any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with weasyprint version 53. I downgraded to version 52.5 and the error was gone.

Comment: I tried this as well. But when i downgrade i get the following error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'can_break_text'"